# Best way to CONVERT python code(with Tensorflow) to Android APK

Tags: python, android, tensorflow

I'm python user and very weak in Java for android APK coding.

Now I want to my python OCR code(Package with so many *.py) to my companies APK.

I heard tensorflow maybe converted TF-lite for APK...

I searched kivy but it seems just a tools for android new app builder, not converting exist *.py codes.

1. I need to entirely code new android APK for java? (Only some like tf.keras.fit() maybe convertable to java via TF-lite?)
2. I just want to OCR when it receive inputs image file and act like just python OCR. what option should I get?? (I really need to study java? it will take some times..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is to create an OCR app and don't have the need to use a custom OCR model built with TensorFlow, I'd suggest you to just use an existing model, as they exist and are super simple to use in Android.

I recommend you to use ML Kit's Text Recognition Package and API:
https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/text-recognition/android

You can find code examples on the page above and a sample app in the link below:
https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart

Google also provides a CodeLab to take you through on a gentle journey of how to build a simple app using ML KIT

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mlkit-android/#0